# Which algorithm does Mathematica use for "RandomSearch"?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algorithm, implementation-details

Recently I have used Mathematica for minimization of certain functions and I have realized that even though it lasts much longer, the method "RandomSearch" functions much better than the other methods for minimization. I am going to use these results for a research article and I thought it would be better if I also indicate the method explicitly. Is it possible to know that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to section "Random Search" in [this guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html), `NMinimize` with method `RandomSearch` scatters points randomly over the search domain and applies the local search method `FindMinimum` with these methods as starting values. For unconstrained optimization problems, the default local method is [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) (or L-BFGS?) (equivalent to calling `FindMinimum` with  `Method -> "QuasiNewton"`) and for constrained optimization problems, an [interior point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method) is used per default (equivalent to calling `FindMinimum` with `Method -> "InteriorPoint"`).

Comment: Indeed, it is mentioned [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#13028) that `FindMinimum[]` uses (L-)BFGS and interior point methods.